# Separating iron from blood

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

How can I separate iron from blood, without doing any damage to the blood/haemoglobin?

I have thought about using a magnet, but apparently iron in blood is not magnetic, and I have also looked at filtration techniques but not sure if that will affect the haemoglobin.

Updated Dec 2017: Let me add some context, I was/am looking for an alternative for chelation therapy such as Desferaloxamine infusions to remove iron in patients with iron overload as a result of repeated transfusions due to anemia

Comment: I vaguely recall some work several years ago from several universities using magnetic nanoparticles coated with something that would bind to the haemoglobin. Outside of the body, they had an apparatus that would inject the nanoparticles, and then magnetically separate them out before putting the blood back in the body. Once separated, the nanoparticles would be treated (can't remember how) to release the haemoglobin.

Comment: Once the iron is removed, it's no longer *Heme b*, but *protoporphyrin IX*.

Comment: According to this study http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a266503.pdf ,
Iron can somehow be released from hemoglobin. I didn't fully understand it as I'm just a student myself, but hopefully it can help you out :)

Comment: This seems like an impossible task.  The iron in blood is primarily _in_ the hemoglobin itself, isn't it?  So at the very least you are going to have to remove the iron from its heme ligand in hemoglobin, from iron-sulfur clusters in various enzymes in red and white blood cells, and from ferritin proteins, etc.

Comment: There was a question from a casual chemistry textbook which is somewhat related. "A legend says that one fine young man gave his beloved an engagement ring made of iron. But that iron was not the trivial one: the young man obtained it out of his own blood. Calculate amount of blood required for a young man to produce $\pu{2.50 g}$ iron. The content of hemoglobin in the blood of an average young men is $\pu{150 g/dm3}$. The molar mass of human hemoglobin is $\pu{68800 g/mol}$. One hemoglobin molecule contains 4 iron atoms." Too bad there is no info how the young man did the tricky part:)

Comment: You can't get the iron out without destroying the haemoglobin and the ability of the blood to carry oxygen. So your premise is wrong. But if you are happy to get the iron anyway, then it can be done but will be messy.

Comment: @matt_black But what about after the haemoglobin has done it's job.

Comment: @naz do you mean after you stop breathing? Or do you mean how can you use out-of-date blood from bloodbanks?

Comment: @matt_black When the person is still alive.

Comment: @naz You do get that you need the iron in your blood to supply oxygen to your body every second of every day, don't you? So at which point has it "done its job"?

Comment: @matt_black Let me add some context, I was/am looking for an alternative for chelation therapy such as Desferaloxamine infusions to remove iron in patients with iron overload as a result of repeated transfusions due to anemia.

Comment: @naz Then you should rewrite the question to add that context as it turns what sounds like a naive and simplistic idea into a good and interesting question.

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to separate iron from blood without damaging the haemoglobin. Iron is a part of haemoglobin, and if iron is removed, the haemoglobin becomes something else. The blood then becomes incapable of transferring oxygen.

Comment: But what about after the heamoglobin has done it's job.

Comment: The iron is recycled when the haemoglobin is alternately reduced and oxidised.   It is never used up in normal service.  It may be that your friend has too much iron in their blood that is NOT in the haemoglobin or they have too much haemoglobin but the 4 iron atoms in the haemoglobin are there to stay. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin

Answer (score -3):

Using the reactivity series, just displace the iron with a more reactive metal.  The Haber process uses carbon to do this but as the heme molecule is mostly made of carbon with a central iron atom, this wouldn't do the trick.  Add heat, pressure and the more reactive metal and you'd get the iron.
http://www.bbc.co.uk/education/guides/zqjsgk7/revision

Comment: What you are proposing won’t work for a number of reasons.